# JPA's bulk update triggers TransactionalEventListener?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a project that uses Hibernate. All objects mapped (with annotations) in the persistence package are automatically updated at the end of transactional methods, if modified.

I want to perform a bulk update with `CriteraUpdate` from JPA 2.1, but I need to change the objects to trigger `TransactionalEventListeners` from Spring.
If I change the objects, and don't call any save methods, hibernate will persist each object, even though I used JPA?

Also, I don't know if the `TransactionalEventListener` will work with the JPA lifecycle instead of Hibernate's (I implement the `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` interface).

Comment: Can you attach the transactional method as well as the listener class? Also which version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JPA methods for orm operations i expect that you are using the EntityManager interface.

That is a good approach as you are interacting with the API instead of the implementation (being Hibernates Session class).
Behind the scenes the EntityManager is calling the Session class anyway and acts just like a decorator, so Hibernate is doing all the work.

If you spring transactional beans are properly configured to work with the Hibernate's SessionFactory, then the listener should be catching the events.

The only thing i can think of is that when triggering bulk operations, the JPA's PersistenceContext is ommited, as opposed to the single entity dml operations and queries. Everything is still wrapped around the transaction so, again, the listener should be invoked.

Just to be sure, place this flag on the @TransactionalEventListener as the specification suggests in case of no transaction being present:

> If the event is not published within the boundaries of a managed transaction, the event is discarded unless the fallbackExecution() flag is explicitly set.